# Programmatically get XAML of an FrameworkElement in SL4

Tags: silverlight, xaml, serialization, silverlight-4.0, frameworkelement

I tried to serialize a `FrameworkElement` with [DavidPoll's](http://www.davidpoll.com/2010/07/25/to-xaml-with-love-an-experiment-with-xaml-serialization-in-silverlight/) `XamlSerializer`, but I get a totally different result than the (right) one that I get with Silverlight Spy. For example with XamlSerializer I get alot of empty tags(like MatrixTransform, ScrollViewer etc.) but not the `ContentPresenter` node that I get with Silverlight Spy. Any idea how to get a clean logical tree at runtime?

Update: I have a form designer program that stores those forms in a DB and at runtime it creates objects (user controls) from that info stored in a DB. Each form is composed of some fields. At runtime it programmatically creats an UserControl that contains all fields. I would like to get the generated XAML, just like I can get it with Silverlight Spy.

[image: Silverlight Spy]

edit: I'm not limited to Silverlight environment, a soltion for a desktop application is valid too.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is: I don't think you can from within Silverlight itself. Sorry.

Once the XAML has been parsed and loaded into framework elements you have already lost information. For instance regenerating a `path` from the in memory object is non-trivial and you won't have access to the internals of the path element from Silverlight code.

Silverlight Spy adds back information that a simple XamlSerializer won't generate. `Silverlight Spy` has no limitations as it is a "real" desktop application, with full operating system access, whereas you want to actually do this in Silverlight itself which is very restricted sandbox environment (*for security reasons*).

Comment: I'm not restricted to Silverlight envirnoment. Any idea how to do what Silverlight Spy do in a desktop application?

Comment: @redman: perhaps if you explain your overall aim I can make a better suggestion?